# Jython: command-line JDBC; no suitable driver SQLServer/Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, jython

I'm trying to move a working set of database calls in Jython from Windows (Server 2008) to Linux (CentOS 6.5).  Calls to jython (2.5.3) are made from the command line under both OS, and connect to either MS SQL Server or Oracle.  The appropriate jar files are included in the startup file:

- Windows (jython.bat):

  ```
  -classpath "C:\jython2.2.1\jython.jar;C:\Projects\lib\ojdbc6.jar;C:\Projects\lib\sqljdbc4.jar;%CLASSPATH%"
  ```
- Linux (jython):

  ```
  -Dpython.path = "/usr/share/jython/ALibs/ojdbc6.jar:/usr/share/jython/ALibs/sqljdbc4.jar:$CLASSPATH"
  ```

Generally attempting:

```
>>> from java.sql import DriverManager
>>> conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxora01.foo.com:1521", "user", "pass")
>>> conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xxxsql01.foo.com:1433;databaseName=DBName", "user", "pass")
```

This works under windows fine.  However, the Linux version keeps giving a "No suitable driver found for..." error.

I have tried to directly load the driver, e.g.:

```
>>> from oracle.jdbc.driver import OracleDriver
>>> DriverManager.registerDriver(OracleDriver())
```

and these command work fine (so the .jar libraries are presumably loaded), but the getConnection still fails.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, here's the answer:

I was confusing the classpath with Dpython.path.  To make jar libraries available to all jython executions (i.e. not having to bother calling them on the command line each time), find the following lines in the jython executable:

```
CP=$JYTHON_HOME/jython-dev.jar

if [ -f "$CP" ] ; then
    [...]
else
    CP=$JYTHON_HOME/jython.jar
fi
```

and add:

```
CP="$CP:[your jar list]"
```